# Delete files older than X days in Jenkins workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

We have a Jenkins job where html reports are generated and placed in workspace/reports. We have been using "Workspace Cleanup Plugin" so we can keep only the last report. We would like to keep the reports created during the past X days and delete the older ones. Is there a way or a plugin that can automate this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a good idea to put something into job's own workspace as an archive that needs to be accessed later. Someone may eventually clean the workspace (either manually or via jenkins pre- or post-build step) and all your precious data and statistics will be gone.

I'd suggest to publish reports using a different directory and then run a cleanup manually in it. You may as well define Jenkins global parameter ([plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Variable+String+Parameter+Plugin)) such as `REPORT_ROOT=/home/${USER}/reports` and use it in job config to save html reports to `${REPORT_ROOT}/${JOB_NAME}`

To cleanup you'd want to run `find ${REPORT_ROOT} -type f -mtime +2 -delete` provided that there is no parent directory created for each separate report. This can be run in a separate job or as subproject to the job that publishes html report or in the job itself. `-mtime +2` means older than 2 days.

If each build has it's own directory for html reports than the cleanup would be `find ${REPORT_ROOT}/${JOB_NAME} -type d -mtime +2 -delete`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As we don't really care about the data (the client  just wanted to "see less files in there" and to find only "the reports from the last 10 days") we skipped the plugin install and just added  
find ${WORKSPACE}/reports/ -type f -mtime +10 -delete  
in a post step in the Execute shell.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PeriodicBackupPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PeriodicBackup+Plugin).

It helps to take back backup of your data periodically and has a BackupExecutor that will check existing backups in each location and delete number of backups older than X number of days defined in configuration.

Check the image for info on configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Configuration Slicing Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Configuration+Slicing+Plugin) that could help you